# Prevent GoLand "Suggestions" from breaking my typing

Tags: goland

I am on a Mac and whenever I type Go code in GoLand, the "suggestions" dropdown pops up. That is okay, so far. But on my machine it is broken. I am using GoLand 2023.2.4.

(A) If I continue typing, GoLand simply "eats" my keypresses and my Code ends up in a total mess. Becomes like -> `fier.tx` instead of `fiber.Ctx`

(B) If I don't continue typing, the suggestions disappear very quickly. -> No code completion available.

The issue disappears if the suggestions seem to be less than 3 or the like.

Except disabling suggestions (as they are very helpful, **if they work**), has anyone found a way to get around this issue, yet?

EDIT: The GIF. After typing "if " it messes up my code. As you can see, it also displays the completion suggestion that shows "return ...", which also "eats" my keypresses.

[image: After typing "if ", GoLand messes up my code]

Comment: Can you please share a GIF with behavior on your GoLand instance?

Comment: There you go. (I need to type 15 characters)